# How to store numbers in Arduino?

Tags: c++, variables, arduino

I have written this to an Arduino.

```
char incomingbytea;
char incomingbyteb;
char incomingop;
char result;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
    incomingbytea = 0;
    incomingbyteb = 0;
    incomingop = 0;
    result = 0;
    bytea:
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incomingbytea = Serial.read();
    Serial.println("1ok");
    Serial.println(incomingbytea);
    goto byteb;
    }
    goto bytea;
    byteb:
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incomingbyteb = Serial.read();
    Serial.println("2ok");
    Serial.println(incomingbyteb);
    goto op;
    }
    goto byteb;
    op:
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incomingop = Serial.read();
    Serial.println("opok");
    Serial.println(incomingop);
    goto oper;
    }
    goto op;
    oper:
  result = incomingbytea + incomingbyteb;
  Serial.println(result);
  Serial.println(incomingbytea);
  Serial.println(incomingbyteb);
  Serial.println(incomingop);

}
```

What I want to do is:
- connect to serial (check)
- collect 2 variables to add/subtract/multiply/divide later (check)
- collect a variable to decide what to do with them 1-add, 2-subtract, etc. (check)
- redirect the script to do the required operation (later)
- print the result to serial (check)

The problem is, when I enter 1 and 1 and 1(whatever, the third one doesn't count now) and I get 98 as a result. Any help? Maybe the variables are wrong?

Comment: What are the unmodified values when you print them at the end?

Comment: The reason I asked is because I think they are probably both 49 if you entered 1 and 1.  The reason for this is that 49 is the ascii value of '1'.  You probably need to convert the ascii character values into actual integers you can do some math with.  It might be as simple as changing your variables to int.  I'm not familiar with how reading from the serial port works on Arduino and can't test, but any detail you can add to the question will help you get a good answer.

Comment: As noted [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19953623/920069) you probably want to use the `parseInt` function.

Comment: @RetiredNinja They are 98, 1, 1, 1. I'll try the parseInt, and update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should know the length of the number, and subtract 48 (48 is the ascii representation of 0) later multiply the number for 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, ... depending of the position of each number.

For example: String "233" to integer, using custom method

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  String Numero1 = "40";
String Numero2 = "50";
double Suma = StringAInt(Numero1)+StringAInt(Numero2);//+ StringAInt(Numero2);
Serial.println(Suma);



}



double StringAInt(String Dato)
{
String Numero = Dato;
char Valores [Numero.length()+1];
Numero.toCharArray(Valores,Numero.length()+1);
double NumeroEnt = 0;

for(int i = 0; i<Numero.length(); i++)
{
    int NumValores = Valores[i];
    NumValores-=48;
    double MultPor = pow(10,Numero.length()-(i+1));
    NumeroEnt += (NumValores*MultPor);
    //Serial.println(NumValores*MultPor);
}
return NumeroEnt;
}
```

Now you only need build a string with the data received from serial port, and you can do math simply.

Comment: Don't subtract `48`, subtract `'0'`. Same behavior, but *much* clearer.